# How OPENDNS works

Tags: http, dns

when site's link broken i found that the firefox show me the unable to connect and server not found problem.

but now they show me openDNS

```
http://guide.opendns.com/main?url=mywebsite&servfail=
```

well what thing are someone else change to make this. i means this great thing that broken things i can see on OPENDNS.

are you know how openDNS work and what user do to make this happen. like if i want to do that how i can use it.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should figure out who your DNS providers are. Use a public [whois server](http://geektools.com/whois.php) or your own `whois(1)` client and look for the "nameserver" entries. Once you know who your nameservers are, then use their administrative interface to add the right IP addresses for hosts in your domain, as well as the reverse pointers if necessary.